# Python Nested dictionary data extraction

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{
  "result" : [{
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 105.570000,
      "start" : 104.970000,
      "word" : "today"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 106.320000,
      "start" : 106.080000,
      "word" : "yes"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 106.590000,
      "start" : 106.320000,
      "word" : "sir"
    }],
  "text" : "today yes sir"
}
```

I want to extract the `start` and `word` variable from the inner dictionary residing within the result.
How do I do this? Any help would be grateful.

Comment: show your code what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Given your dictionary:**

```
my_dict = {
  "result" : [{
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 105.570000,
      "start" : 104.970000,
      "word" : "today"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 106.320000,
      "start" : 106.080000,
      "word" : "yes"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 106.590000,
      "start" : 106.320000,
      "word" : "sir"
    }],
  "text" : "today yes sir"
}
```

**Then**

```
start = my_dict['result'][0]['start']
word = my_dict['result'][0]['word']
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the dictionary you gave:

```
dict ={
   "result" : [{
       "conf" : 1.000000,
       "end" : 105.570000,
       "start" : 104.970000,
       "word" : "today"
     }, {
       "conf" : 1.000000,
       "end" : 106.320000,
       "start" : 106.080000,
       "word" : "yes"
    }, {
       "conf" : 1.000000,
       "end" : 106.590000,
       "start" : 106.320000,
       "word" : "sir"
     }],
   "text" : "today yes sir"
}
```

And this works to get the all the "word" and "start" values:

```
list = dict.get('result')

for i in list:
     print(i.get("start"))
     print(i.get("word"))
```